# Remove DT, DD if DT doesn't contain actual value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am listing the shop information on website using tags DL-DT-DD. The information will be generated and placed by server.

```
<dl class="description-cols">

<dt>Shop Name</dt>
<dd class="divider"> US Master Autos</dd>

<dt>Toll Free</dt>
<dd>Not Available</dd>

<dt>Fax</dt>
<dd>(305) 345-42324</dd>

<dt>Email</dt>
<dd class="divider"> Not Available</dd>

<dt>Website</dt>
<dd class="divider">
      <a target="_blank" href="http://www.google.com">http://www.google.com</a>
</dd>
</dl>
```

If the value of any row is Not Available, I would like to remove the corresponding row(DL & DT). I would like to do this using jquery or javascript.

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/umeshpatil86/y4S2B/4/) for testing. I would like to remove rows of Toll Free and Email

Comment: Why don't you do that at the server as well?

Comment: +1 that's great idea, but php engine, that doesn't listen to me, puts the data inside the tag dynamically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will help:

```
$('dd:contains("Not Available")').each(function() {
    $(this).prev().remove();
    $(this).remove();
});​
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y4S2B/2/)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way,

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/y4S2B/5/)**

```
$('dd').each(function(){
   if($.trim($(this).text()) == "")
   {
      $(this).prev('dt').remove(); 
      $(this).remove();    
   } 
});​
```

Comment: +1. works, but I needed one should enter inside DL and then loop :)